# как сделать рамку при наведении с необычными границами?

Tags: css, border

как сделать такой элемент у рамки при наведении на карточку товара
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```css
body {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 10px;
  background: #bbb;
}

.card {
  display: block;
  height: 250px;
  border-radius: 25px;
  background: #fff;
  padding: 20px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: relative;
}

.card::before,
.card::after {
  content: '';
  display: none;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border: 10px solid transparent;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-100%);
}

.card::before {
  border-top-color: #fff;
  top: 5px;
  z-index: 2;
}

.card::after {
  border-top-color: #bbb;
  top: 6px;
  z-index: 1;
}

.card:hover {
  box-shadow:
    0 0 0 5px #fff inset,
    0 0 0 6px #bbb inset;
}

.card:hover::before,
.card:hover::after {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="card">Карточка</div>
<div class="card">Карточка</div>
```

Comment: треугольничек в самом верху - его нету ?

Comment: @De.Minov благодарю